# iOS std::length_error::~length_error() crash

Tags: ios, crash, symbolicatecrash

In my App, I used the C++/Boost lib also.
It's weird that all the crash logs are related to the std::length_error().

Can anyone give some clues?
Any comment is welcome.

```
124 Thread 8 Crashed:
125 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30a70350 __pthread_kill + 8
126 1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33dff11e pthread_kill
127 2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x33e3b96e abort
128 3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36f5bd4a abort_message
129 4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36f58ff4 default_terminate()
130 5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x32c69a8c _objc_terminate()
131 6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36f59078 safe_handler_caller(void
132 7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36f59110 std::terminate()
133 8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x36f5a50e __cxa_throw
134 9   Navigatio                       0x00d9f65a std::length_error::~length_error() + 10115470
135 10  Navigatio                       0x0ed9f732 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10115686
136 11  Navigatio                       0x00d9a438 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10094444
137 12  Navigatio                       0x00d99b52 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10092166
138 13  Navigatio                       0x0059bc32 std::length_error::~length_error() + 1711974
139 14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33de130e _pthread_start
140 15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x33de11d4 thread_start + 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your symbolication is wrong. Look at those offsets:

```
0x00d9f65a std::length_error::~length_error() + 10115470
0x0ed9f732 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10115686
0x00d9a438 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10094444
0x00d99b52 std::length_error::~length_error() + 10092166
0x0059bc32 std::length_error::~length_error() + 1711974
```

Those numbers are crazy. That would require `std::length_error::~length_error()` to be over *9 megabytes* of code size.

So either something went horribly wrong during symbolication (such as the wrong binary being used to provide symbols), or there's no symbols in the 9 megabytes of code after `std::length_error::~length_error()`.